# Filter JSON data into a CSV list

Tags: python, json, linux, python-2.7, csv

My goal is to take the host names out of this JSON file (output.json) and put them into a CSV list (newoutput.csv) using python, with the end result looking like:

> TheHost1, TheHost2, TheHost3

There are a couple hundred entrys, with the hostnames under "specific_data.data.hostname"

Here is a snippet of what the output.json file looks like:

```
 [
      {
        "adapter_list_length": 3,
        "adapters": [
          ...
        ],
        "internal_id": "...",
        "labels": [
          "...",
          "..."
        ],
        "specific_data.data.hostname": [
          "TheHost1"
        ],
        "specific_data.data.last_seen": "...",
        "specific_data.data.network_interfaces.ips": [
          "...",
          "...",
          "..."
        ],
        "specific_data.data.network_interfaces.mac": [
          "..."
        ],
        "specific_data.data.os.type": [
          "..."
        ]
      },
      {
        "adapter_list_length": 3,
        "adapters": [
          "...",
          "....",
          "...",
          "..."
        ],
        "internal_id": "...",
        "labels": [
          "...",
          "Router"
        ],
        "specific_data.data.hostname": [
          "TheHost2"
        ],
        "specific_data.data.last_seen": "...",
        "specific_data.data.network_interfaces.ips": [
```

I'm new to python, and any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: first of all I would [serialize](https://realpython.com/lessons/serializing-json-data/#:~:text=The%20json%20module%20exposes%20two,a%20string%20in%20JSON%20format.) the json as a python object. Then I would use the [map](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/map) function to just extract out an array of the "specific_data.data.hostname" property. Then I would use the [string.Join()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/join) function to convert this into a csv string

Comment: please post what you have already tried and what is actually the problem. JSON file reading? CSV output writing? extracting hostnames? ...?

Comment: `specific_data.data.hostname` is an array as opposed to a string. Can there be multiple entries in that array? My solution posted below assumes the array has exactly one value.

Comment: I don't really know what to try, like I said, I'm very new to python, and not even sure where to really start. I've got this json files saved, and am just trying to filter it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate the list of dictionaries and extend a "hosts" list with the list of hosts found in each record. When you have all of the values, build the comma separated string.

```
import json
# python 2.7 needs different open
import codecs
filename = "output.json"
# json is usually utf-8 encoded but this is not 100% guaranteed
data = json.loads(codecs.open(filename, encoding="utf-8"))
hosts = []
for record in data:
    if "specific_data.data.hostname" in record:
        hosts.extend(record["specific_data.data.hostname"])
# assuming hosts are all ascii
with open("hostnames.csv", "w") as fileobj:
    fileobj.write(",".join(hosts))
    fileobj.write("\n")
```

Comment: Sorry I should have specified, I need to read/open the file (output.json), do the filtering, and then export it as (hostnames.csv). How would I do that?

Comment: @laser_gunns Firslty please specify your original question to make it clear for others to answer and for future reference

Comment: I juste noticed its python 2.7, so need to change that file open a bit.

Comment: ....and python 2.7 is end of life, so obligatory note on upgrading to 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

The following sets the `csv` variable to a string with comma-separated hostnames.

```py
import json
object = json.loads(snippet)
csv = ', '.join(x['specific_data.data.hostname'][0] for x in object)
```